# Why did Gilbertus Albans choose Lampadas as the home planet of the Mentat School?

Tags: dune, brian-herbert

If Mentats are so smart...

Why would the founder of the Mentat School, Gilbertus Albans, choose Lampadas as the school's home planet when It's also the home planet of Manford Torondo and the Butlerian jihadis?

apparently no Mentat projections said it's a bad idea to study thinking machines and hide Erasmus's memory core on the cental planet of the anti-technology jihad. Is there a logical reason for his founding and continued operation of the school on Lampadas?

In universe answers only please. opinion based criticisms of the Brian Herbert books are not in the scope of the question and will be down voted.

Comment: best place to hide something in where your enemy's least expect it.

Comment: @Himarm "When your enemy offers you two targets ... strike at a third." -- Davram Bashere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gilbertus Albans, being much older than Manford Torondo due to the life extension treatment given to him by Erasmus, selected the planet as a good place for the school far before Manford took up residence there. Manford considered the planet quaint, while Gilbertus selected it due to its isolation to keep the students "free from distractions", and avoiding the dangerous swamp creatures would help them to keep their mental edge.

Frankly, Gilbertus should have just packed up and moved the school as Erasmus suggested several times, possibly to Ecaz, where saffo is made.

Comment: Interesting points. Are you able to add references for these?

Comment: true. After reviewing the chronology, Rayna Butler was killed 8 years after the battle of Corrin. Therefor, there is an 8 year window for the school to be established before Torondo even assumes leadership. Your answer, that the Mentats were there first, is valid.